# Where to add own repository class and interfaces in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web, web-deployment

I am attempting to add custom repsitories (contract and Eloquent) in Laravel.
I don't understand where to add them and how to bind with services.
Can any body show the best example for add own wn repository class and interfaces in Laravel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I follow. Laravel already contains Eloquent. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a directory in your App folder.Like - **App/Acme**
2. Create a Repository File in Acme folder. **App/Acme/CustomRepository.php** and also import the name space on that Repository file.Like- **namespace Acme;**
3. Use your model. Like- **use App\Models\User;**
4. In you controller inject the CustomRepository Class.Like-

   class CustomController extends Controller{

   private $customRepo;

   ```
   public function __construct(CustomRepository  $customRepo)
   {
   $this->customRepo= $customRepo;
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

The way I like to structure my Laravel Code would be:

Models - `App\Models\*`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

class Model extends BaseModel
{
    // 
}
```

Contracts - `App\Repositories\Contracts\*`

```
<?php 

namespace App\Repositories\Contracts;

interface Repository
{
    // All the common methods for eloquent like - all, paginate, find, where, etc...
}
```

Repository - `App\Repositories\Db\*`

```
<?php 

namespace App\Repositories\Db;

class ExampleRepository
{
    // All the CRUD related methods here...
}
```

Services - `App\Services\*`

```
<?php 

namespace App\Services;

class ExampleService
{
    // All the logic & business related methods here...
}
```

This is what I like to structure my code in a laravel way.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For make usage of repository pattern (if it is that what you want to say), you have two options, one of it is to implement under a self-defined namespace (let's say `App\Repositories`), an interface with the methods you want to use in all your repositories, maybe `AbstractRepository` or something like that, this one choice is painful because of the lot of code you have to write, the other choice (what I would use), is to install the following package https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository, is really useful and already have inside a lot of methods, just follow the instructions of the readme file and you will not have any issue at all implementing this pattern, hope it helps, bests! ;)

Comment: I have small project and I don't want to add extra package. I want to know directory Structure.

Comment: Well, in that case, use this tutorials, they explain it there, links above, bests!

https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/
http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I need.

Comment: @VijayKumarVerma you don't need to use repositories if you use Eloquent. Do you have any reason to use repository?

Comment: Well, I'd understand that if you'd have some super great project and  want to add an extra layer to keep things clear, but if you have a small project like you say, I think that you can work with Eloquent out of the box